java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adyen.checkout.card.util.CardValidationUtils"
I am working on a Flutter app. In this app I am integrating Adyen payment gateway. To achieve this I have created a separate plugin to handle encrypting the card and other api calls to Adyen. In this process I have implemented encryptCard method from Adyen Android SDK.
I am facing following error when I am trying to use encrypt:
E/AndroidRuntime(31103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(31103): Process: com.mycompany.my_mobile, PID: 31103 E/AndroidRuntime(31103): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/adyen/checkout/card/util/CardValidationUtils; E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at group.mycompany.adyen_payment.AdyenPaymentPlugin.validateCardNumber(AdyenPaymentPlugin.kt:85) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at group.mycompany.adyen_payment.AdyenPaymentPlugin.onMethodCall(AdyenPaymentPlugin.kt:38) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) E/AndroidRuntime(31103): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adyen.checkout.card.util.CardValidationUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~rCuroo2Bbmn6AQLg2tVGAg==/com.mycompany.my_mobile-gZQNg2av6NcxnGdFFX1knQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~rCuroo2Bbmn6AQLg2tVGAg==/com.mycompany.my_mobile-gZQNg2av6NcxnGdFFX1knQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~rCuroo2Bbmn6AQLg2tVGAg==/com.mycompany.my_mobile-gZQNg2av6NcxnGdFFX1knQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]] E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) E/AndroidRuntime(31103):    ... 14 more I/Process (31103): Sending signal. PID: 31103 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device. the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
I have following method in PaymentPlugin.kt file:
private fun encryptCVV(
        call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result
    ) {
        val resultData = JSONObject()
        try {
            val encryptionKey: String? = MY_ENCRYPTION_KEY
            val cvv: String? = call.argument("securityCode")

            val rawCard: UnencryptedCard = UnencryptedCard.Builder().setCvc(cvv!!).build()

            val encryptedCard: EncryptedCard = CardEncrypter.encryptFields(rawCard, encryptionKey!!)
            resultData.put("encryptedCVV", encryptedCard.encryptedSecurityCode)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            resultData.put("error", e.message)
        }
        result.success(resultData.toString())
    }



I tried to change min sdk version.

Its best to drop feedback, concerns around Checkout or other Adyen built SDKs on their relevant github rep. Relevant teams do respond promptly and push changes fairly quick as and when determined to be crucial.
Link: https://github.com/Adyen
